# Do other Klingons have a choice if they want to follow a discommendation?

Tags: star-trek, klingon

I've recently rewatched Star Trek - Deep Space 9 - S03E03 - The House of Quark. At the end of the episode, Quark goes to his knees and says that this is no combat but an execution. He therefore wants to have it that way and taunts D'Gor to execute him. When D'Gor wants to proceed, Gowron stops him and then discommendates him for having no honor.

D'Gor looks, unbelieving, at the other Klingons, following Gowrons example.

According to Memory Alpha, the highest ranking Klingon iniates the discommendation:

> The ceremony in which this punishment was meted out was simple. The Klingon about to be discommended would state, "tlhIH ghIj jIHyoj." ("I fear your judgement.") He would then be called "biHnuch" ("Coward") by the highest-ranked Klingon present, who would subsequently cross his or her arms in front of his or her chest, and turn his or her back on the recipient, while others followed suit one by one until almost all Klingons had their backs turned.
>
> From the [Memory Alpha Article on Discommendation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Discommendation#Ceremony)

However, in D'Gors case, it wasn't a ceremony. He didn't say "tlhIH ghIj jIHyoj.", Gowron simply called it and everybody else followed. Would the other Klingons on Gowrons court have a choice not to discommend D'Gor or is the ruling of one Klingon (even in case he was not the Chancellor) final and all others follow?

Comment: You could choose to ignore the wishes of the Chancellor. If you wished to face the Chancellor in combat (and probably die).

Comment: @Valorum I mean, the chancellor is a special case. But what if somebody else discommendates somebody?

Comment: Then they'd stab you in the back and laugh at you.

Comment: There are social and cultural near isomorphisms there that are both a little scandalous and entertaining.  I could see a broken parallel of it happening in "legally blonde". Does the head Klingon really call someone something that crudely approximates bey-otch, then  then cross her arms, and turn her back?  Its a mini-shun, and it has drama, but every warrior whose been through battle knows you never take your eyes off an enemy.